# How can I compare two arrays of objects including n number of children arrays of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

If I had control over an `IteratorModel` object that told me information I need to compare the children arrays how could I compare the two arrays?

An `IteratorModel` would be an object like this:

```
var iteratorModel = {
    next: {
        name: 'Next',
        next: {
            name: 'NextNext',
            boolProp: 'HighlightNextNext'
        }
    }
};
```

The `name` property gives us the name of the next level of data in our arrays. Each level can have additional information as well, but that isn't important to the question.

So if this was the basic structure of comparing `arrA` and `arrB` how could I use the `iteratorModel` to compare nested arrays?

```
$.each(arrA, function (i, valA) {
    $.each(arrB, function (b, valB) {
        // what to do here?
    });
});
```

More info:

Given two arrays that follow this general structure:

```
MasterArray: [
    { 
        id: 0,
        NestedArr: [ 
            {
                id: 0,
                NestedNestedArr: [
                    {
                        id: 0
                    }
                ],
                More Objects...
            } 
        ],
        More Objects...
    },
    More Objects...
]
```

How could I dynamically compare them not knowing the level of NestedArrays, but instead given an `IteratorModel`?

Comment: What are you comparing?  What data exactly is `IteratorModel` telling you?  I don't quite understand.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I will update my question.

Comment: Why do you want to compare arrays with each other? To determine which of them is "greater" or "smaller" than the other, or what type of comparison do you mean?

Comment: So the objects in the array will look like `{Next:"something to compare first", NextNext:"something to compare second"}`?

Comment: @Bergi Let's say `arrA` is my clients data and `arrB` is an array telling me which IDs in `arrA` should have a boolean value switched from true to false. This can include children arrays IDs. That is just one example.

Comment: @edhedges: But what would the result of a comparison between those two arrays be? Or are you just asking about how to iterate them (both at the same time - `zip`ping them) given such an "iterator model"?

Comment: @Bergi I would be modifying `arrA` given the some info in `arrB`.